# What's wrong with this PHP code (two dimensional array)?

Tags: php, arrays

After some time, I get the following warning:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in (...) on line 8

```
<?php

$arrnumbers = array(1=>array(10,20,30),2=>array(40,50,60));

for($indexRow =1; $indexRow <=count($arrnumbers); ++$indexRow)
{
    for($indexColumn =0; $indexCoulumn <count($arrnumbers[$indexRow]);++$indexColumn)
    {
    printf("%d ", $arrnumbers[$indexRow][$indexColumn]);
    }

print("<BR>");
}
?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use a `foreach` instead of `for`-loops. Much cleaner when dealing with arrays.

Comment: You also have a typo in your code, which is why it doesn't work. You have `$indexCoulumn` instead of `$indexColumn` in the second `for`-loop.

Comment: I'd still recommend using a `foreach`-loop, it's a lot simpler! Take a look at my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented on your question, I'd suggest using a `foreach`-loop for dealing with arrays, it's much cleaner and simpler.

The code below first loops through the first sub-array and prints it, then does a newline and does the same thing for the second sub-array. The output will be

> 10 20 30
>   40 50 60

```
<?php
$arrnumbers = array(1=>array(10,20,30),2=>array(40,50,60));

foreach ($arrnumbers as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key=>$value) {
        printf("%d ", $value);
    }

    print("<br />");
}
?>
```

You can read the full documentation on `foreach`-loops at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).